# How to format ws xlsx in react js?

Tags: reactjs, xlsx

> - I can change the value of column A1 when exporting excel but I want to change the style of 1 column in excel.
> - Here is my export function:
> - Someone please help me thanks.

```
> const exportToExcel = (excelData, fileName, wsCols) => {
>     const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(Heading, {
>       header: ["identifier", "new_players", "bet", "win", "margin", "players_played", "play_sessions", "operator_total", "company_total"],
>       skipHeader: true,
>       origin: 0 //ok
>     });
> 
>     ws.A1.s = {
>       font: {sz: 14, bold: true, color: '#FF00FF'}
>     };
> 
>     ws["!cols"] = wsCols;
>     XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, excelData, {
>       header: ["identifier", "new_players", "bet", "win", "margin", "players_played", "play_sessions", "operator_total", "company_total"],
>       skipHeader: true,
>       origin: -1 //ok
>     });
>     const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
> 
>     const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
>     const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
>     FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);   };
```